# How to play asterisk's recorded calls from a php application?

Tags: php, html, asterisk

I have an Issable (Asterisk based VoIP solution) in my company. I am developing an application in PHP which part of it I need to play the recorded calls. the application is located in a separate server from the Issabel. I already have access to the sound file path which for example is:

```
/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2018/10/20/rg-600-2122238507-20181020-223323-1540062203.100880.wav
```

When I want to play this file using HTML's audio tag by adding the ip address of the issabel server at the beginning of this path, nothing happens and even the Isaabel blocks my IP address since the server is password protected. Any solution to play the file located in this path from my PHP application would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need to stream the content programmatically. Maybe Google for something like "how to stream wav files in php".

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks bro you gave me the clue I will post the complete solution to this question in the next post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FélixGagnon-Grenier mentioned the solution to this problem is solved by streaming the audio to the application. I have created stream.php in the server containing the following code:

```
 <?php
    $filePath = $_GET['file'];
    $fileName = basename($filePath);
    $fp=fopen($filePath, "rb");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName');
    header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize($filePath)."    ");
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
```

and in my application which is located in another server I used HTML5 audio tag to call the file and send the path to the audio file with GET method:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="https://<SERVER_IP>/stream.php?file='.$callRecordPath.'" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and it worked for me!
Thanks

Comment: Solid. Careful however, because that script could let someone execute any file on your server's disk (any file to which the php process user's has access, which can be a lot). Maybe you could validate part of the path before serving, but it also may not be that much of a danger.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yep, good point. The path validation seems a rational approach to the hole.